# How to filter Endpoint with have no agent cortex xdr with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get endpoint with have no agent but I have no idea about to filter or get output it

this code below to output get all endpoints and out as IP-Address how to filter json about get endpoint have no agent

from code I can get all endpoints but want to get just endpoint with have no agent

```py
import requests

# Please change to your tenants API Key and ID#
api_id = 'x'
api_key = 'x'

headers = {
    "x-xdr-auth-id": str(api_id),
    "Authorization": api_key
}
parameters = {}

# Please change to match your Tenants API Url #
res = requests.post(url="https://api-subdomain.xdr.region.paloaltonetworks.com/public_api/v1/endpoints/get_endpoints/",
                    headers=headers,
                    json=parameters)

# importing the module

import re

# Regex&Filter to get only IPv4 address format
fstring = str(res.json())
fstring = fstring.replace(',', '\n')
ipString = re.findall(r'(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})', fstring)
for i in range(len(ipString)):
    print(ipString[i])
```